# How to convert mysql data base table data in json using php

Tags: php, mysql, json

How to convert MySQL data base table into JSON data using PHP. Is there any way to do this?

Below is the php code I am using:

```
<?php 
$host = "emriphone.db.6420177.hostedresource.com"; 
$user = "emriphone"; 
$pass = "Light12-"; 
$database = "emriphone"; 

$linkID = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die("Could not connect to host."); 
mysql_select_db($database, $linkID) or die("Could not find database."); 

$sth = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ProviderAppointmentListings");
$rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
   $rows[] = $r;
}
print json_encode($rows);
?>
```

Comment: It would be good if you show us the suggested json data format. In general @Secator is right.

Comment: @greut Call to undefined function: json_encode() in

Comment: Upgrade PHP bro! You're living in that Dark Age where PHP couldn't `goto`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try like this:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table");
$rows = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}
print json_encode($rows);
```

If you don't have `json_encode` add this before the code above:

```
if (!function_exists('json_encode'))
{
  function json_encode($a=false)
  {
    if (is_null($a)) return 'null';
    if ($a === false) return 'false';
    if ($a === true) return 'true';
    if (is_scalar($a))
    {
      if (is_float($a))
      {
        // Always use "." for floats.
        return floatval(str_replace(",", ".", strval($a)));
      }

      if (is_string($a))
      {
        static $jsonReplaces = array(array("\\", "/", "\n", "\t", "\r", "\b", "\f", '"'), array('\\\\', '\\/', '\\n', '\\t', '\\r', '\\b', '\\f', '\"'));
        return '"' . str_replace($jsonReplaces[0], $jsonReplaces[1], $a) . '"';
      }
      else
        return $a;
    }
    $isList = true;
    for ($i = 0, reset($a); $i < count($a); $i++, next($a))
    {
      if (key($a) !== $i)
      {
        $isList = false;
        break;
      }
    }
    $result = array();
    if ($isList)
    {
      foreach ($a as $v) $result[] = json_encode($v);
      return '[' . join(',', $result) . ']';
    }
    else
    {
      foreach ($a as $k => $v) $result[] = json_encode($k).':'.json_encode($v);
      return '{' . join(',', $result) . '}';
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function: json_encode() in this gives error using this code

Comment: [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.json-encode.php) requires PHP 5.2.0+. What version do you use?

Comment: Server version: 5.0.91-log this is given on my data base which i am using

Comment: Have you added the `json_encode` before you actually use it ?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    $username = "user_name"; 
    $password = "password";   
    $host = "url";
    $database="database";

    $server = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password);
    $connection = mysql_select_db($database, $server);

    $myquery = "SELECT date,close FROM data2";
    echo "hi";
    $query = mysql_query($myquery);

    if ( ! $query ) {
        echo mysql_error();
        die;
    }    
    $data = array();    

    for ($x = 0; $x < mysql_num_rows($query); $x++) {
        $data[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
    }

    echo json_encode($data);     

mysql_close($server);

?>
```

This code converts your mysql data in phpmyadmin to json. Works perfect

Comment: PHPMyAdmin is an application providing an admin UI to MySQL database backends, not a data hosting platform in and of itself. Besides, The OP made no mention of PHPMyAdmin.

Comment: if we don't format the date into proper ISO format, how will programming languages like Java detect it during parsing on client apps?

Answer (score 1):

As long as you are using MySQL server 5.7 or later, you can produce JSON data by using just SQL and nothing more, that is, you need PHP just to pass the SQL and get the JSON result. For example:

```
SELECT JSON_OBJECT( 'key1', column1,
                    'key2', JSON_OBJECT('key3', column2)) as fοο;
```

There is more that `JSON_OBJECT`! Please check this page:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-function-reference.html

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean the data in a MySQL-database table right?

In that case, have a look at PHP's [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

You can fetch the data from the db into an array and then covert it to JSON.

Answer (score 0):

put the resultset of the query into an array and then use json_encode

```
$sql="Select * from table";
$l= array();
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $l[] = $row;
}
$j = json_encode($l);
echo $j;
```

you may use id table as index of the array.

Comment: you  must upgrade php or install http://pecl.php.net/package/json, look at the version http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Answer (score 0):

using this code :

```
json_encode($array)
```

for example :

```
public function SELECT($tableName,$conditions){

      $connection = mysqli_connect($hostname, $userName, $password,$dbName);
      try {

        if (!$connection)
            die("Connection failed: " . $connection->connect_error);
        else
        {
            $qry = "";
            if(!$this->IsNullOrEmptyString($conditions))
               $qry = "SELECT * FROM `".$tableName."` WHERE ".$conditions;
            else
               $qry = "SELECT * FROM `".$tableName."`";

            $result = mysqli_query( $connection, $qry);
            if($result) {
                $emparray = array();
                while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
                    $emparray[] = $row;

                echo(json_encode($emparray));           
            }
            else
                echo(mysqli_error($connection));       
            } 
            mysqli_close($connection); 
      } catch(Exception $ex) {
          mysqli_close($connection);
          echo($ex->getMessage());
      }  
 }
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<?php
$username = "user_name"; 
$password = "password";   
$host = "url";
$database="database";

$server = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password);
$connection = mysql_select_db($database, $server);

$myquery = "SELECT date,close FROM data2";
echo "hi";
$query = mysql_query($myquery);

if ( ! $query ) {
    echo mysql_error();
    die;
}    
$data = array();    

for ($x = 0; $x < mysql_num_rows($query); $x++) {
    $data[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
}

echo json_encode($data);     
mysql_close($server);
```

?>