# create custom json array from database result in php?

Tags: php, mysql, json, web-services

Hi I have some table say fro example table1 ,table2 in my mysql databse.
I need to get following json result from php.
Can anyone suggest how to achieve this?
any good tutorial doing same is also helpful.
I am able to convert database result in simple json response but custom response is something difficult for me.

```
{
response:ok
tables:[
{
    name:table name
        data:[
                {
                fieldname1:value1
                fieldname2:values2
                },
                {
                fieldname1:value1
                fieldname2:value2
                }
                .
                .
            ]               
},
{
    name:table name1
        data:[
                {
                fieldname1:value1
                fieldname2:values2
                },
                {
                fieldname1:value1
                fieldname2:value2
                }
                .
                .
            ]               
},

]
}
}
```

Comment: You will need to create a custom array with the data you want and the organisation you want, and the call `json_encode` with this array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from [How to convert mysql data base table data in json using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9785649/how-to-convert-mysql-data-base-table-data-in-json-using-php), once you have your table names you can do for each of them.

```
$result = array();
$result['response'] = 'ok'
foreach ($tables as $tableName) {       
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tableName");
    $rows = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        $rows[] = $row;
    }
    $result['tables'][] = array(
         'name' = $tableName,
         'data' = $rows
    )
}
print json_encode($result);
```

Comment: @ leorossi Hi,We are not using $result anywhere in our json output ?I guess we should use it.What do you say?

Comment: I just mispelled the variable name.  $result is what you are jsonizing and echoing.